# Mentioning an answerer or commenter name in the question

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, etiquette

When amending a question to address a point made in an answer or a comment, is it OK to mentioning the answerer name? (e.g., at the end of the question, "To answer Bob's comment: blah blah blah")

Answer (score 2):

It's OK, but it's unnecessary.

If you're adding information to the post that is helpful in answering it (which presumably you are, if you're editing in an answer to a comment), then it doesn't need to be denoted as an answer to a comment. It's just helpful information.

If you're not, it belongs in a comment, where you can reply directly to Bob.

It's not such a massive issue that you should edit it out if you see it in others' posts, but you don't need to do it in your own.